# How to view the information in your Rails app Database?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a blog app and want to know how I can view the tables I create in my database.

I did: `rails g model tweet id:integer status:text person:string`

Comment: You can use `rails dbconsole` if you want to see it via SQL, or enter `rails console` and view it with Ruby/Rails commands (e.g., enter `Tweet.first` should show the first record of `Tweet`).

Comment: If you are providing an answer, why put it in a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways:

1) Run `rails console` or `rails c` and type in something like `Tweet.new`. You should view that object and it's attributes that way.

2) You can view the `schema.rb` in the `db` folder.

3) You can look at the actual migration file located in `db/migrate` folder.

I prefer the first way since you're going to get an accurate assessment of how the database looks and you can play around with that data.

Comment: If you're looking for data on an existing instance of a class, you can call Object.find(instance.id)

Comment: Right. I think for this question though the OP is wanting to just get the schema of his database.